# How do I know which SSL version is used by SoapClient in php?

Tags: php, ssl, soap-client, handshake, sslv3

We have an integration with a service via SOAP, we use [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php).
Due to [POODLE ssl3 vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POODLE) service provider will disable SSLv3 on those servers.

I couldn't find any useful information about which SSL version SoapClient uses in PHP.
I also don't understand how do I use specific version of SSL with SoapClient and PHP<5.5 (since version 5.5 there is an option in SoapClient constuctor, `ssl_method`).

It seems like the only way for PHP 5.3 and SoapClient to specify version of SSL is to use [streaming context for ssl](http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php). As far as I understand I can specify [`ciphers list`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html#CIPHER_LIST_FORMAT), but this is black-waters to me. How do I know which ciphers to use to be sure client wouldn't want to perform a request via SSLv3?

All in all, should I really be worried? It seems like it's servers responsibility to tell client which SSL version to use, isn't it? And if I didn't specify the exact (3) version in a past, our service provider's SSLv3 shutdown will not affect us?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, Registered stream socket transports: tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls. So, which one it will use? :)

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing the SSL *library* with the SSLv3 *a cipher*.  The library PHP is using is the one available when it was built or packaged for your system. You can find out which specific version from `php_info()` or similar commands.

To disable SSLv3 (a cipher), simply use `TLSv1` as the cipher. To do that, pass in the optional [*options* array](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) to the SoapClient constructor:

> The `ssl_method` option is one of SOAP_SSL_METHOD_TLS,
>   SOAP_SSL_METHOD_SSLv2, SOAP_SSL_METHOD_SSLv3 or
>   SOAP_SSL_METHOD_SSLv23.

Here you would use `SOAP_SSL_METHOD_TLS`.

Comment: I would, yes, if my PHP version was 5.5+ :) I've got 5.3.29 across a dozen of servers, lots of dependencies, etc. I mean, I can not switch to 5.5 now

Comment: As I understand it, the SSL handshake will do the trick, my PHP was compiled with ssl, sslv3, sslv2 and tls support, so client will initialize the transaction, it will say which transport methods it can use and the server will response with a certificate and a list of methods it supports, thus both client and server can negotiate on the transport issue. Are my thoughts correct?